# javascript replace line breaks AND special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, special-characters, line-breaks

I added a ".replace" to my alert to remove/replace line breaks and hard returns and it works great.

```
alert((foo + bar).replace(/(\n|\r)/g,''));
```

I want to add a similar piece to replace special characters.  This works on it's own, but how do I combine the two so it removes breaks AND spec characters?

```
 .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'_');
```

This was my best guess at it and it's not working....

```
 alert((foo + bar).replace(/(\n|\r)/g,''),(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'_'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace with different strings like you showed in your example

```
alert((foo + bar).replace(/(\n|\r)/g,'').replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'_'));
```

If both can be replaced with an empty string

```
alert((foo + bar).replace(/(\n|\r|[^a-zA-Z0-9])/g,'')
```

Comment: Prefect.  The 2nd option is exactly what I need.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

**Version # 1**

You can add a new method to the String prototype property

```
String.prototype.stripSpecialChars = function() {
  return this.replace(/(\n|\r|[^a-zA-Z0-9])/g,'');
}
```

and use

```
(foo + bar).stripSpecialChars();
```

**Version # 2**

You can also just write a function that does the same thing

```
function stripSpecialChars(text) {
  return text.replace(/(\n|\r|[^a-zA-Z0-9])/g,'');
}
```

and use

```
stripSpecialChars(foo + bar)
```