# Text to HTML with Javascript and Auto Refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that pulls info from a text file and displays it in html.
The text I pull is in this format with line changes for each event.

```
2017-09-20 19:01:13 INFO Application - Starting Application 
2017-09-20 19:01:13 INFO Application - No active profile set, 
2017-09-20 19:01:22 INFO Application - Started Application in 10.177 seconds
2017-09-20 19:22:32 INFO Util - Detected configuration changes
```

When I run my script it turns out like this in my html page:

2017-09-20 19:01:13 INFO Application - Starting Application 2017-09-20 19:01:13 INFO Application - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default 2017-09-20 19:01:22 INFO Application - Started Application in 10.177 seconds (JVM running for 12.187) 2017-09-20 19:22:32 INFO Util - Detected configuration changes.

Anyone know if it can be displated exactly as its in the text file on the website?
Thank tyou.

```
    <span id="botlog">Loading data...</span>
    <script>
    function radioTitle() {
    var url = 'demotext.log'; 

    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: url,
       dataType: 'text',
       success: function(data) {

       $("#botlog").html(data)
    },

    error: function(e) {
       console.log(e.message);
    }
    });

    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

    setTimeout(function(){radioTitle();}, 5000);
    setInterval(function(){radioTitle();}, 5000);

    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Put it inside a `<pre>` tag

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Is there a way to pull only the last 10 lines from the text file?

Comment: It's hard to answer, not knowing how your script works

Answer (score 0):

You can either put the response in `<pre>` tags (which preserve line spaces and breaks) or, if you like, insert `<br />` tags with the following Regex expression:

```
replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the linebreaks:

```
replace(/(\n|\r)/g,'<br />'));
```

See also:
[javascript replace line breaks AND special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520897/javascript-replace-line-breaks-and-special-characters)